# GLSL Grayscale Shader removes transparency

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shader

I'm very new to GLSL and started with a simple greyscale shade. I used the code of GamesFromScratch's tutorial:

vertexshader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

Fragmentshader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main() {
        vec3 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).rgb;
        float gray = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;
        vec3 grayscale = vec3(gray);

        gl_FragColor = vec4(grayscale, 1.0);
}
```

The effect and the problem: Everything is rendered in grayscale only, but transparent parts of the textures become white. For example: A simple filled circle is usually drawn as a circle. Now its a circle within a white box. Next to the removed transparent parts also changes on the alpha are not visible.

Comment: You're setting the alpha of the output to `1.0`. Why do you expect to still see transparency if you make the output fully opaque?

Comment: Unrelated, but everything involving `v_color` can be removed from this shader since it's unused.

Comment: divide by 3 doesn't give 100 correct result. The answers below are the correct way to do gray-scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your fragment shader. You create a `vec3 color` imagine (r,g,b) then you set gl_FragColor to a vec4 (r,g,b,a). Use use the first three from grayscale and then set the "a" to a hard coded alpha value of 1, removing any transparency.

You could get the rgba from the sampler and use its alpha in the final vec4.

Also if you are looking for a more true grayscale conversion the general standard is

`color =  0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

Comment: Just a little nitpicking: "Also if you are looking for a more true grayscale conversion the general standard is ...".  What you quote here is the RGB to Luma conversion as specified in ITU-R BT.601. However, the nice thing about standards is that there so may of them to chose from. For example, BT 701 uses (0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722) andSMPTE 240M (0.212, 0.701, 0.087).  The actual coefficients will depend on the definition of the RGB color space one is working with.

Comment: thanks, that helps me lot. No idea how I could overlook this part. Now it looks pretty obvious. But oe problem is still there: I use often
 `sprite.draw(batch)` and changed alpha. So normally sprites become transparent, but when the shader is activated the sprite's alpha-value is ignored. Also `batch.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);`has no effect when the shader starts

Answer (score 5):

I think these changes will help you.

```
vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
float gray = dot(color.rgb, vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114));
gl_FragColor = vec4(grayscale, color.a);
```

In my changes, I read color with alpha from texture and apply it to output.

Comment: That's the GLSL way of doing it. Should be marked as correct answer.